# redirect won't work with variable php

Tags: php

this is my code, I am trying to redirect the header to a page defined by the variable "$direct" but whenever I run the script it shows an error and says

"Not Found

The requested URL /Resource id was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Please help!!

```
$sql1="SELECT direct FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql1);
Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
header('location: '.$direct);
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Any errors ? does it get stuck on that page or? and I see 'texts' inside your code that aren't commented out.

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions use PDO instead. & what are you getting in $count?

Comment: $count gets the number of rows that contain $username and $password in order to make sure it is only 1

Comment: print_r($count) returns 1 ? if yes check the path of $direct instead?

Comment: what do you mean check the path of direct instead? @ShashankShah